# MySQL - Cannot add Foreign Key constraint - missing index

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create these 2 tables -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PartsOrder(
    VIN VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    order_number VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    order_date DATE NOT NULL,        
    PRIMARY KEY (VIN, order_number),    
    FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES Vehicle (VIN)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Part(
    part_number VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    VIN VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    order_number VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(1000),  
    cost FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (part_number, VIN, order_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (VIN) REFERENCES Vehicle (VIN)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (order_number) REFERENCES PartsOrder (order_number)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

However, this is throwing the error -

> Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'part_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'partsorder'.

Shouldn't adding the UNIQUE constraint be enough to use the attribute order_number as the foreign key?

Comment: From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html): "MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan."

Comment: @PM77-1 But doesn't `order_number ... UNIQUE` create an index on that column?

Comment: If `order_number` is unique by itself, why do you need a multi-column primary key?

Comment: I also wonder about making `order_number` unique in the `Part` table. That means you can't use the same part in more than one order.

Comment: This whole thing doesn't seem to make sense. It basically means that an order can only have one part, and a part can only be in one order.

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Agreed, making the order_number unique doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `order_number` in the `PartsOrder` table is **not** unique - the combination of `vin` and `order_number` is.

You could either add a unique constraint on `order_number` (which would make the existing one redundant), or define the foreign key on these two columns:

```sql
FOREIGN KEY (vin, order_number) REFERENCES PartsOrder (vin, order_number)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that we could use a combination of attributes as the foreign key. thanks a lot.